# liquibase include file and dbDoc Or update fails

Tags: migration, database-migration, liquibase

I have directory structure for migrations as follow:

db1:

- latest/ (triggers,functions,procedures)
- tables/
- v000/master.xml
- update.xml

## db1/update.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <include   file="v000/master.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

db2: (try to include db1/update.xml) schema here , as I need to extend/add to db1 schema )

- update.xml

## db2/update.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">


    <include   file="../db1/update.xml" />

</databaseChangeLog>
```

db1> **liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml update , successful**

but

db2 > **liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml validate**

show validation errors for tables included from db1/v000/master.xml

```
<include file="tables/12_createTable_audiences.xml" />
```

`Error Reading Migration File:tables/12_createTable_audiences.xml .....`

if I fix the error by following changes (for each table: in db1/v000/mater.xml)

```
 <include file="../tables/12_createTable_audiences.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

db2 > **liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml validate/update works fine**

but

db2 > **liquibase --changeLogFile=update.xml  dbDocs ~/docs/db1**

fails on table 12_createTable_audiences.xml

Does any one know how to fix these (path issues) ? Why update and dbDoc commands behave differently for same paths ?

thanks for your kind support.

Comment: Raise a JIRA ticket against liquibase project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `relativeToChangelogFile` attribute try to specify the path in include file from the root. Something like

```
<iuclude file = "./Update/db1/update.xml" />
```

Comment: I did same , but one of the things break. Let me try again .

Comment: Try specifying all the paths from the root.